# Proof that limit points are unique

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

I ams having problems to prove that the limits points of a sequence are unique. For example given the following sequence
\begin{equation}
x_n=(-1)^n+\frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}
To find the limit points, I establish these subsequences
\begin{equation}
y_n=x_{2n}=(-1)^{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}=1+\frac{1}{2n}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z_n=x_{2n+1}=(-1)^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}=-1+\frac{1}{2n+1}
\end{equation}
Where it can be seen that
\begin{equation}
y_n\rightarrow 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
z_n\rightarrow -1
\end{equation}
My question is how can I prove that these are the only two limit points of the sequence.
I suppose that it is related to the fact that
\begin{equation}
Image(f(n))+Image(g(n))=\mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
Being
\begin{equation}
f(n)=2n\; \; \; \;  
g(n)=2n+1
\end{equation}

Comment: If you pick any other point $y \in \mathbb{R}$, can you show that there is always a small enough open interval around it such that it hits $x_n$ at most finitely many times?

Comment: Any subsequence contains infinitely many terms of one of your subsequences (which forces any limit to be 1 or $-1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1,-1\}$. Then, take $\varepsilon=\min\{|a+1|,|a-1|\}$. Since $a\ne\pm1$, $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n}=1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{2n-1}=-1$, there is some $N_e\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N_e\implies|x_{2n}-1|<\frac\varepsilon2$$and there is some $N_o\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N_o\implies|x_{2n-1}+1|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$But then, since each natural number is either even or odd, if $n$ is large enough, then you have $|x_n+1|,|x_n-1|<\frac\varepsilon2$. So, since $\varepsilon\leqslant|a+1|,|a-1|$, $|x_n-a|>\frac\varepsilon2$. Since the inequality $|x_n-a|>\frac\varepsilon2$ takes place for every $n$ is large enough, $a$ cannot be the limit of a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Answer (score 3):

If the sequence had a limit point $p$ other than $-1$ or $1$, then there would exist a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$  such that $x_{n_k}\to p$.

Note that the set $S:=\{n_k:k\in \mathbb N\}$ can't have an infinite intersection with the set of even natural numbers because if it did, then $(x_{n_k})$ and $(y_n)$ will share a subsequence $s$. Since every subsequence of a convergent sequence must converge, $s$ will also converge to $p$ and to $1$, which is impossible.

Similarly, the set $S$ can't have infinite intersection with the set of all odd numbers.

Therefore $S$ can't be an infinite set, which contradicts our assumption that $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence.

It follows by contradiction that no subsequence of $(x_n)$ can have a limit point other than $-1$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $L$ is another number, not equal to $1$ or to $-1$. Then we can find neighborhoods of $1$, $-1$, and $L$, all mutually disjoint. Since the sequence is eventually inside the union of the neighborhoods of $1$ and $-1$, then it's eventually outside the neighborhood of $L$, so $L$ is not a limit point.

Comment: G Tony Jacob's. My answer is similar to yours. If you feel it is just a copy of yours I delete. Wanted to be a bit more concrete.

Comment: @PeterSzilas, it doesn't bother me. It's nice to have the answer couched in both kinds of language: more concrete, and more..... topological? Cheers :D

Comment: @PeterSzilas, I notice that you made the same mistake I did, which I just corrected in my answer. There is no reason to assume that the third point is a limit point, since we never use that assumption. It's just a number distinct from $\pm 1$.

Comment: G Tony Jacobs. A nice way of looking at it. Thanks:))

Comment: G Tony Jacob's. I wrote: There is another limit point (means a not equal to $\pm 1$).What should I correct?

Comment: @PeterSzilas, I changed mine to just make $L$ another *number* not equal to one of the two known limit points, not another limit point.

Comment: G Tony Jacobs. Does saying another limit point a not imply that a not equal 1 or - 1? Set it up slightly differently from you. Assumed that there is an a, and found a contradiction.

Comment: @PeterSzilas, it's not really a proof by contradiction unless you use the assumption that the other point is a limit point. What the argument itself shows is that if $a\ne 1$ and $a\ne -1$, then $a$ is not a limit point. Nowhere is the contradictory hypothesis used.

I admit it's kind of a pedantic point. The argument is clear, in any event.

Comment: @PeterSzilas, to answer your direct question: Yes, saying that $a$ is *another* limit point does imply that $a$ is distinct from $1$ and $-1$. However, assuming something that (one-directionally) implies what you really need is assuming something stronger than you need. It doesn't make any part of it false, just kind of logically clunky.

Comment: G Tony Jacobs. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: G Toni Jacobs. Thank you for pointing out that that my original post set up, as a proof by contradiction, was a bit " clunky".  Going over it and your comments you were absolutely right, not much of a contradiction. I feeel I have learnt something Thank you for your patience:))

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\ L \not\in \{-1,1\}\ $ is a limit point of $\ \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ and define $\ \delta := \min \left\{\ \frac{\vert L-1 \vert}{2} ,\ \frac{ \vert L-(-1) \vert }{2}\  \right\}.\ $

Show that $\ (L-\delta, L+\delta) \cap \{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N} }\ $ is finite and conclude.

Answer (score 2):

One more attempt:

Consider a point $a\not =\pm 1.$

There are open neighborhoods of $a, - 1,1$ that do not intersect each other: $U_a, V_{-1}, W_{1}$.

There is a $n_0$ s. t. for $n \ge n_0$  $x_n \in V_{-1}$ or $x_n  \in W_1$.

There are only finitely many indices $n <n_0$, s. t. $x_n$ not in $V_{-1}$ or $W_{1}.$

Hence:

$a$ is not a limit point of $x_n$.

Recall:

$a$ is a limit point of the sequence $x_n$ if for every open neighbourhood of $a$ there are  infinitely many indices $n$ s.t. $x_n$ is in this neighbourhood.